# Simplify the design for auto-suggestion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a rather complicated construction in my code, it is in const matchedSuggestions.
This construction is responsible for auto-suggestions.
For example: there are several male names (Adam, Adrian, Arnold, Mike). The user enters the first letter "A" and sees auto-suggestions - Adam, Adrian, Arnold. Then he enters the letter "D" and remains in auto-suggestions - Adam, Adrian. And so on.

Is it possible to somehow simplify this part of the code?

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setInput(value)

  if(value.length < 1) { setSuggestedTags([]); setIsValid([]);return; }
  
  const matchedSuggestions = tagSuggestions.filter((s) => {
    return s.slice(0, 2).search(value.slice(0, 2)) > -1 
        && s.slice(0, 1).search(value.slice(0, 1)) > -1
        && s.slice(0, 3).search(value.slice(0, 3)) > -1
        && !tags.includes(s)
  })
  setSuggestedTags(matchedSuggestions); 

  if (e.target.value) {
    setIsValid(() => /^[1-5][0-9]?[0-9]?$|^100$/.test(e.target.value));
  } else {
    setIsValid(true);
  }
  setInput(value);
};
```

Comment: Nina's implementation is technically different from what you have currently, but I'm pretty sure her answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the length of the input string and use it as index for slicing. Even better, you could use `startsWith` and if wanted normalized to upper or lower case, like

```
 value = value.toLowerCase();             // normalize
 tagSuggestions.filter(s =>
     s.toLowerCase().startsWith(value) && // or includes(value) in case you want to validate part of the string
     !tags.includes(s)                    // what is this for?
 );
```